# Alternative for RODBC package to make connection from R to MS Access

Tags: r, ms-access, rodbc

I am trying to make a connection from R to a database file in Microsoft Access. I used to use the RODBC package for this.

However, the package recently got updated and now it's not compatible anymore with my version of R (I cant easily upgrade my version of R since its used for business purposes).

These are the lines of code I use where the RODBC package comes into play:

```
install.packages("RODBC")
library(RODBC)  
access_file     <- "file_name.accdb"
cfs <- odbcConnectAccess2007(access_file)   
df1 <- sqlFetch(cfs, "G_Company")
```

Does anyone know an alternative for the RODBC package?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you just install an older version of the package? `devtools::install_version("RODBC", version = "<insert version here>", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")`

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But I would prefer to have a permanent solution that isn't reliable on a certain version of the package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Tidyverse way to connect with databases, packages `DBI` and `odbc`:

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
connection <- dbConnect(odbc(), .connection_string = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\\file_name.accdb;")
df1 <- dbReadTable(connection , "G_Company")
```

This has multiple advantages, such as allowing you to embed SQL statements in RMD files, and allowing you to integrate with `dbplyr` to form queries from dplyr statements.

However, if you're going to use old R versions, I often use the `checkpoint` package, which allows me to install multiple versions of packages side-by-side and avoid incompatibilities between them by fetching packages from before a specified date.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The first three lines worked fine (I managed to make a connection to the Access database file). However, R says it cant find the `sqlFetch` function. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @matthew I normally work with a dbplyr workflow, so was not fetching tables the proper way because then everything works a little differently. Try the following, that should properly read the entire table.

Comment: Thanks, that works! One follow-up question: is it also possible to specify the `file_name` and work directory outside the `dbConnect` function? In this way, one can just adjust the `file_name` and work directory variables at the start of the code, instead of manually scrolling through the code to change the `file_name` in case a new file is used.

Comment: Well, you can just use `paste0` to paste the file name onto the connection string (and combine that with `file.path` and `getwd` to get what RODBC actually uses internally).

Comment: I am not entirely sure how this would look like inside the `dbConnect` function. Could you write out the one-liner given `paste0`, `file.path` and `getwd` ?

Comment: `dbConnect(odbc(), .connection_string = paste0("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=", file.path(getwd(), "file_name.accdb"), ";"))`. Seems fairly straightforward to me.