# Reading an .mdb file into R

Tags: ms-access, rodbc

Using Windows 10 Enterprise and R 4.1.2, I am trying to read MS Access .mdb files into R. It seems the RODBC package is the best (only?) choice available.

I've set the R version to the 32-bit version and tried variations on the following:

```
library(RODBC)
ch <- RODBC::odbcConnectAccess("C:/live.mdb")
```

In all cases, I get

> Warning messages:
>
> 1. In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) :   [RODBC] ERROR:
>    state HY000, code -1028, message [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access
>    Driver] Cannot open database '(unknown)'.  It may not be a database
>    that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt.
> 2. In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) : ODBC connection failed

I can open and browse the MS Access database in Access 2016 without issue.

Comment: _It seems the RODBC package is the best (only?) choice available_ Nope. I highly recommend switching to using the DBI and odbc packages, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62433795/7296893). RODBC has some oddities, especially when working with long text fields, and DBI + odbc offers many advantages, such as working with dbplyr.

Comment: Thanks @ErikA! I'll check it out.

Comment: A work around would be to export the data from Access to a comma delimited file (.csv) and then connect R to the csv file.

Comment: Thanks, @mazoula. I was trying to avoid relying on Access, but it seems unavoidable, particularly since I need this solution to be available/access on different Windows/MS-Office workstations. (NOTE: I haven't tried the DBI package yet). The solution I'm using at the moment is 1) download the MDB files from the source; 2) save/over-write previous downloaded files;  3) link/read the MDB files in to Excel; 4) read/import that Excel file into R. My anticipated workflow is that use can simple download and save the files and then go directly to R.

Answer (score 0):

I swear I tried this earlier, but it didn't work. I guess I fat-fingered it. Nonetheless, this option is working for me in the 64-bit version.

```
ch <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:/live.mdb")
```