# R Session Aborted due to 32bit Access Connection using RODBC

Tags: r, ms-access, rodbc

I am trying to connect to a 32bit access using R lang 4.1.3 32bit using the following code chunk,

```
library(RODBC)
db_path <- "C:/Pathway/To/Access.accdb
con <- odbcConnectAccess2007(db_path)
```

when running that chunk I have a critical failure and get the R Session Aborted window.

Is there any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: RODBC has some issues. If it isn't a major rework, I recommend DBI + odbc, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62433795/7296893)

Answer (score 0):

Try without the typos:

```r
library(RODBC)
db_path <- "C:/Pathway/To/Access.accdb"
con <- odbcConnectAccess2007(db_path)
```

And/or study here:

[How to connect R with Access database in 64-bit Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070706/how-to-connect-r-with-access-database-in-64-bit-window)

Comment: Typos fixed, previously working and seems to stop with an update. Was hoping someone else has encountered this. It is being run in a 32bit environment so that link doesn't provide much insight.